# Error while browsing MBeans in WLST

Tags: python, wlst, oam

Trying to access an OAM identity asserter through WLST.

I use the `cd` command to navigate through Security, Authentication Providers to the list of Providers. I try `cd` to the `OAM` Identity Asserter and it produces the following error:

```
Error while browsing MBeans : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.security.wls.oam.providers.asserter.OAMIdentityAsserterMBean
```

Answer (score 1):

After some further research I think I may know why this is occuring.. I found information that tells me that a jar file named oamAuthenProvider.jar should exist within the server directory at /lib/mbeantypes, this does not exist. Which I think is what’s causing the class not found exception.

Comment: I have found that including the oamAuthenProvider.jar helps Weblogic integrate with OAM and prevent the java.lang.ClassNotFoundException I was receiving.

Comment: Indeed. I can confirm that this jar MUST exists under both  `.../wlserver/server/lib/mbeantypes`  and `domain-home/lib`